# Total Value of minutes based on the start and end time value

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image: This is what I want to achieve - to show the minutes' total value on the last input]

I have these html tags but I would like to add PHP code or javascript to show the minutes value and then save it to my database. Saving to the database is already good for me, I have no problem with it. Only the preview of the total minutes' value.

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="stime" class="form-control" required name="stime" type="time" value="12:00" />
    <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="etime" class="form-control" required name="etime" type="time" value="12:30" />
    <label for="etime">End Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col col-sm">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="time" class="form-control" name="time" type="text" value="30" />
    <label for="time">Time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to a) update the time value when the start or end value is changed b) be able to send the form to a PHP script which saves this to the Db?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(function calculateTime() {
  let start_time = $('stime').value;
  let end_time = $('etime').value;
  let diff_time = $('time');
  diff_time.value = end_time - start_time;
});
```

Comment: Do I need to edit the value:"" here?

<div class="col col-sm">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input id="time" class="form-control" name="time" type="text" value="30" />
    <label for="time">Time</label>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Nothing happens...